# Build tensorflow dataset iterator that produce batches with special structure

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset

As I mentioned in the title I need batches with special structure:

```
1111
5555
2222
```

Each digit represent feature-vector. So there are `N=4` vectors of each classes `{1,2,5}` (`M=3`) and batch size is `NxM=12`.

To accomplish this task I'm using Tensorflow Dataset API and tfrecords:

- build tfrecord with features, 1 file for each class
- create instance of Dataset for each class, and initialise iterator for each of them
- to produce batch I sample `M` random iterators from list of iterators and from each iterator produce `N` feature-vectors
- then I stack features together
- ...
- batch ready

My concern is that I have hundreds (and maybe thousands in the feature) of classes and storing iterator for each class doesn't look good (from memory and performance perspective).

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the list of files ordered by class, you can interleave the datasets:

```
import tensorflow as tf

N = 4
record_files = ['class1.tfrecord', 'class5.tfrecord', 'class2.tfrecord']
M = len(record_files)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(record_files)
# Consider tf.contrib.data.parallel_interleave for parallelization
dataset = dataset.interleave(tf.data.TFRecordDataset, cycle_length=M, block_length=N)
# Consider passing num_parallel_calls or using tf.contrib.data.map_and_batch for performance
dataset = dataset.map(parse_function)
dataset = dataset.batch(N * M)
```

*EDIT:*

If you need also shuffling you can add it in the interleaving step:

```
import tensorflow as tf

N = 4
record_files = ['class1.tfrecord', 'class5.tfrecord', 'class2.tfrecord']
M = len(record_files)
SHUFFLE_BUFFER_SIZE = 1000

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(record_files)
dataset = dataset.interleave(
    lambda record_file: tf.data.TFRecordDataset(record_file).shuffle(SHUFFLE_BUFFER_SIZE),
    cycle_length=M, block_length=N)
dataset = dataset.map(parse_function)
dataset = dataset.batch(N * M)
```

NOTE: Both [`interleave`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#interleave) and [`batch`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#batch) will produce "partial" outputs if there are no more remaining elements (see docs). So you would have to take special care if it is important for you that every batch has the same shape and structure. As for batching, you can use [`tf.contrib.data.batch_and_drop_remainder`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/batch_and_drop_remainder), but as far as I know there is not a similar alternative for interleaving, so you would either have to make sure that all of your files have the same number of examples or just add [`repeat`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#repeat) to the interleaving transformation.

*EDIT 2:*

I got a proof of concept of something like what I think you want:

```
import tensorflow as tf

NUM_EXAMPLES = 12
NUM_CLASSES = 9
records = [[str(i)] * NUM_EXAMPLES for i in range(NUM_CLASSES)]
M = 3
N = 4

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(records)
dataset = dataset.interleave(tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices,
                             cycle_length=NUM_CLASSES, block_length=N)
dataset = dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.batch_and_drop_remainder(NUM_CLASSES * N))
dataset = dataset.flat_map(
    lambda data: tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
        tf.split(tf.random_shuffle(
            tf.reshape(data, (NUM_CLASSES, N))), NUM_CLASSES // M)))
dataset = dataset.map(lambda data: tf.reshape(data, (M * N,)))
batch = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    while True:
        try:
            b = sess.run(batch)
            print(b''.join(b).decode())
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError: break
```

Output:

```
888866663333
555544447777
222200001111
222288887777
666655553333
000044441111
888822225555
666600004444
777733331111
```

The equivalent with record files would be something like this (assuming records are one-dimensional vectors):

```
import tensorflow as tf

NUM_CLASSES = 9
record_files = ['class{}.tfrecord'.format(i) for i in range(NUM_CLASSES)]
M = 3
N = 4
SHUFFLE_BUFFER_SIZE = 1000

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(record_files)
dataset = dataset.interleave(
    lambda file_name: tf.data.TFRecordDataset(file_name).shuffle(SHUFFLE_BUFFER_SIZE),
    cycle_length=NUM_CLASSES, block_length=N)
dataset = dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.batch_and_drop_remainder(NUM_CLASSES * N))
dataset = dataset.flat_map(
    lambda data: tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
        tf.split(tf.random_shuffle(
            tf.reshape(data, (NUM_CLASSES, N, -1))), NUM_CLASSES // M)))
dataset = dataset.map(lambda data: tf.reshape(data, (M * N, -1)))
```

This works by reading `N` elements of every class each time and shuffling and splitting the resulting block. It assumes that the number of classes is divisible by `M` and that all the files have the same number of records.

Comment: this looks good. But can I randomly sample `cycle_length` sub-batches? And I guess I also need to cut each file to make it same size and divisible by `block_length` if I want to be sure that all batches have equal shapes and the same number of feature vectors per class in each batch

Comment: @Aiven I have added an alternative with shuffling, plus some additional comments.

Comment: I meant shuffling on class level. For instance: 1 batch - 1,5,3 classes, 2 batch - 2,7,1 classes, each new batch has random classes and their feature vectors. If I put shuffle before interleave then it will be applied only once. Probably it is not even possible to do what I want with single dataset instance.

Comment: @Aiven I added a different approach to something like what you said, although it is somewhat limited.